# Error: Adding data in a map in Firestore but the the new data saves as an array inside the map instead of a field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this `colorMap` from firestore which is a `map`.

[image]

What I'm trying to do is add more data in the  `colorMap`. Let's say I have these:

> Green: 50
>
> Black 50
>
> Red 20

And I wanted to add `Pink : 80`. But what my code currently does is, if I'll add `Pink: 80`, the `Pink` becomes an array instead of a field. Also, there might be instances where I would need to add more colors and quantity in one submission (e.g. `Pink : 80`, `Yellow : 20`, `Brown : 60`)

This is what happens when I save it in Firestore.

[image]

**Expected output**
Once I'll add `Black : 80`, it should be the same data types with the other colors as well.

**Submitting in firestore:**

```
  //converting colorList to colorMap (map)
  const colorMap = colorList.reduce(function (map, obj) {
    map[obj.color] = obj.colorStocks;
    return map;
  }, {});

  const colorSave = Object.keys(colorMap);
  const qty = Object.values(colorMap);

  const handleSubmit = (index) => async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const ref = doc(db, "products", state);
    await updateDoc(ref, {
      ...product[index],
      [`colorMap.${colorSave}`]: qty,
    });
    console.log("done");
  };
```

This is the console for the `colorMap`:

[image]

**Form**

```
 {colorList.map((singleColor, index) => (
                    <div key={index}>
                        <>
                            <>
                                <TextField
                                  label="Color"
                                  name="color"
                                  type="text"
                                  id="color"
                                  required
                                  value={singleColor.color}
                                  onChange={(e) => handleColorChange(e, index)}
                                />
                                <TextField
                                  label="Stocks"
                                  name="colorStocks"
                                  type="number"
                                  id="colorStocks"
                                  required
                                  value={singleColor.colorStocks}
                                  onChange={(e) => handleColorChange(e, index)}
                                />
                            </>
                        </>
                      </div>
                      <br />
                        //button to remove the row of the textfield
                    </div>
                  ))}
                    //button to add the row of the textfield
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Object.keys(colorMap)` and `Object.values(colorMap)` [will return arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys). So what you are providing in the `updateDoc()` method are not single values rather they are arrays. That is the reason why the value is stored as an array instead of a map.

Now let me explain this a bit further by taking an example -

I have taken a hard coded map for convenience.

If the map has only one object i.e `const data={'Pink':90}`, then by running the following code as you did,

```
async function updateData() {
 
const data={'Pink':90};
const colorSave=Object.keys(data);
const qty=Object.values(data);
const document=doc(db,'collectionId','documentId');
await updateDoc(document,{[`colorMap.${colorSave}`]:qty});
}
```

will add the data in the Firestore like the following -

[image]

If you have more than one object in the map i.e. `const data={'Pink':90,'Red':70}`, then by running the above code as you did, will add the data in the Firestore like the following as `colorSave` is an array and also `qty` is an array. The field name will be the elements in `colorSave` separated by commas.

[image]

So the correct way to update the document here is to use a for loop and inside that update the document. The sample code will look something like following -

```
async function updateData() {
const data={'Pink':90,'Red':70};
const colorSaveArray=Object.keys(data);
const qtyArray=Object.values(data);
const document=doc(db,'collectionId','documentId');
for (let index = 0; index < colorSaveArray.length; index++) {
  const colorSave = colorSaveArray[index];
  const qty = qtyArray[index];
  await updateDoc(document,{[`colorMap.${colorSave}`]:qty});
}
}
```

The above code will update the document like the following as you want it to be -

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it

Comment: Glad to know that it helped!

Comment: I kinda have a problem though, the initial `...product[index] `  inside the ` updateDoc`  won't work anymore

Comment: You can update that before the for loop with a separate `updateDoc()` method.